# Save Delphi Project

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I created a project in Delphi 7, How to save the project with all packages, to be ready to use on other computers that do not have installed by default those packages. Maybe somebody knows a good tutorial. Sorry for the question if I formulated it incorrect.

Comment: you mean to open the project in delphi on another computer ? or do you mean to run the build application on another computer ?

Comment: Hello, I mean to run the built application on another computer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is not how Delphi works.  Packages are separate from projects that use them.  There is no way to tell the IDE to save them all together.  You will have to deploy the packages themselves onto the other computer and install them into the IDE before you can then open any projects that use the packages.

Answer (score 0):

To run the build application in Delphi 7 on another computer you only need to copy the exe to that other computer. There is no need to collect packages, the Delphi compiler creates an executable that works standalone.

If you used a ClientDataSet than make sure that in your source you have incluced MidasLib in your uses, if you do not than you have to supply Midas.dll also.

That should be all.
If this does not works, than tell us what error message you get when running the built application on the other computer.

Comment: that has nothing to do with Delphi or the application you build with it. You are missing the driver to connect with access, which can be downloaded from microsoft.com